# pom:2.7.1 failed to transfer from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 during a previous attempt

Tags: eclipse, maven

How to remove this error. I have tried all the mentioned in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

1. solution with "force update snapshot/dependencies".
2. solution with "maven clean/ install".

but the error is still there.

Comment: You are using `http` instead of `https` which is really a security issue. (Details: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html)

Comment: Can you run man with -X to get the debug notes?

Comment: No. I guess. I am using windows and this command isn't working on cmd or powershell.

Comment: Paste the exact error message and the artifact it fails to download so that we can also verify for you that it actually exists.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.7.1 failed to transfer from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect timed out pom.xml /RestAPI_Project line 1 Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: I want to know from where the maven is getting the info to use "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2". May be If I can change that it will work.

Comment: When you deleted the cache what were the errors?

Comment: Few analysis question - When you deleted the cache what were the errors?  Can we get more details on what the pom is - can you paste it - perhaps removing your company details first?  Are you behind a proxy?  You can change the site that maven looks to by adding mirror details - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: deleting the cache, you mean, maven clean? for maven clean error is : Downloading from : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.7.1/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.7.1.pom .............and then timeout happen. pom is same as we get from spring intializr project with web, jpa, mysql dependendencies.

Comment: by deleting the cache I mean going into the .m2 and deleting it.  Can you show us any information about mirrors in your settings.xml?

Comment: @lupin the problem is in your setup not being able to connect to repo1.maven.org. You can paste your ~/.m2/settings.xml file and try to debug from there. All in all, `curl -v https://dtools.ipsoft.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.7.1/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.7.1.pom` should succeed too.

Comment: I uninstalled maven, eclipse and reinstall eclipse and now it is working file. seems like some issue with previous installation.